# How does stripe handle subscription with no payment in customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for a subscription based project and recently found out that you can subscribe without the user requiring payment information with a trial period.

How does stripe handle the user once the trial period ends but didn't any payment information?

When I look at customers it says that there isn't any default source.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the trial period, the Subscription would renew its billing cycle. This would make the Subscription move to `status: "active"` and send `customer.subscription.updated`. A new Invoice would also be created. This would send the `invoice.created` event.

An hour or two later, the Invoice would be automatically finalized and Stripe would attempt to pay it. The payment would fail since the Customer has no payment method attached. This would send an `invoice.payment_failed` event. The Invoice would be retried multiple times as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/automatic-collection). Stripe can even send emails to your Customer asking them to add/update their card.

If all payment retries fail, the Subscription would then be canceled automatically.